# WASM app OK in VS2019 but not from GitHub Page

Tags: github, webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am new to GitHub and Blazor WASM. I am a WinForm developer and converted a Visual Studio (VS2019) WinForm to WASM using BlazorWebAsembly, NetCore 5.0 with VS2019.
This is on https://burtstewart.github.io/BlazorWAMapp1/.  The Page loads from VS using IIS fine but via Browser I get a "An unhandled error has occurred. Reload "

Can anyone provide help?   thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github pages are made to primarily host applications created with [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/). See [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) for more information.

So hosting a WASM blazor app is not the primary scope. You can see that the page is not loading because the Github Page Webserver doesn't know how to serve the request. Running it locally, within an IIS, the IIS loads all the requested files, which then bootstrap the WASM application.

[image]

You can follow [this tutorial](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-aspnet-blazor-webassembly-to-github-pages), which helped me to accomplish the task. And you will see that there are plenty of tasks involved.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have seen tutorial, but I will repeat.

Comment: Thank You "Just the benno".  after 2 attempts with the tutorial you suggested I have the page up.  So if you ever need to anti-coagulate a Patient with  intravenous Heparin, then please use my page!!

Comment: Congratulation on your success. Could you mark the questions as answered, so that others can find it more easily?